# On click display a specific query in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am working on my angular cocktail app, and i managed to get to the part that i display all cocktail in my database (only showing names), but now i would like if i click on a certain cocktail to display full content in a specific div.

Can i do it with ng-click somehow?

my current html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bar Master</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <!--ANGULAR-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>

    <!--Yanone font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">

    <div ng-controller="cocktail">
        <div class="container cocktail_list">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center><h2>COCKTAILS THAT WE SERVE</h2></center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <ul>
                    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="drink in cocktails | filter:globalSearch">
                    <li>
                        </i><button class="cocktail_button">{{" " + drink.Name + " "}}</button>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="recipe" class="col-sm-4 cocktail_image">
                COCKTAIL NAME AND INGREDIENTS....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center>
            <div id="seachBoxes">
                <h2>Search for a cocktail by its name or ingredient</h2>
                <input type="text" ng-model="globalSearch.$" class="global_search">
            </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

controller.js:

```
var fileX={
    "records": [
        {
            "Name":"Martini",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"Lemon peel vodka gin"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Autumn Leaves",
            "Price":"9",
            "Ingredients":"gin vermouth lemon peel"
        },

        {
            "Name":"7 Naranja",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"Havana Club Añejo ice cube Apricot Brandy Angostur"
        },
        {
            "Name":"A Day At The Beach",
            "Price":"6",
            "Ingredients":"malibu rum amaretto orange juice grenadine"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Appletini",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"De Kuyper Sour Apple Absolut vodka"
        },
        {
            "Name":"B-52",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"Kahlue (coffee liqour)  Irish cream liqueur (Baileys) Premium Orange Liqueur"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Black Sunset",
            "Price":"8",
            "Ingredients":"Malibu Black orange juice Cranberry juice "
        },
        {
            "Name":"Blue Lagoon",
            "Price":"5",
            "Ingredients":"ananas juice Havana Club 3 Años rum DeKuyper Blue Curaçaa"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Hollywood",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"Absolut vodke DeKuyper Raspberry ananas juice"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Red Splash",
            "Price":"8",
            "Ingredients":"tequilla red wine Graffigna Centenario Malbec agave juice lemon or lime juice grapefruit soda"
        },
        {
            "Name":"Rum Cola",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"Havana Club 3 Años rum  Coca-Cola lemon lime slice"
        },
        {
            "Name":"The Godfather",
            "Price":"7",
            "Ingredients":"whiskey amaretto"
        },



    ]
}

var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('cocktail', function($scope){
    $scope.cocktails = fileX.records;

});
```

So i want to click on a button that represents a specific cocktail and display the full content of that coctail in div with id 'recipe'. Aka display: {{" " + drink.Name + " " drink.Ingredients + " "}} for the selected cocktail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the jQuery function, you should use `ng-click` and have a new scope variable where you set all the data of the current drink to, and based on that you should have:

In controller add a empty scope and a function to set to the empty scope.

```
$scope.currentDrink = null;
$scope.setCurrentDrink = function(drink){
  $scope.currentDrink = drink;
}
```

Then use this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="drink in cocktails | filter:globalSearch" ng-click="setCurrentDrink(drink);">
     <button class="cocktail_button">{{" " + drink.Name + " "}}</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And edit the `#recipe`:

```
<div ng-if="currentDrink != null" id="recipe" class="col-sm-4 cocktail_image">
            Dump the params for currentDrink....
            {{currentDrink}}
</div>
```

I'm sorry if it is a bit ugly, writing on my phone.

I also manage to create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B1m7zqXJw5Zji9fphcew?p=preview)

Comment: Beat me by 2 minutes. Here's [my version of the same idea](http://jsfiddle.net/g642su0v/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, just got 1 more question, how can i get a better/cleaner display of data? instead of {"Name":"Autumn Leaves","Price":"9","Ingredients":"gin vermouth lemon peel"}, something like Autumb leaves <br/> 9 <br/> gin vermouth lemon peel ?

Comment: Ah, i see at @Alex K solution, thanks to both of you!